# What is this called? Why is it allowed?

Tags: theory, terminology, chord-progressions, key

"Golden Train" by Justin Nozuka (YouTube link below) is in the key of Ab major. However he uses a Cb major chord throughout the song, which is not in the key of Ab major.  It sounds good and works well for creating tension, but I want to know why it sounds good if it's not in the key. Pay special attention to the word "away" in the chorus, that is the Cb chord I'm talking about.

The progression in the chorus is `Ab Cb Bbm`.

Comment: Is the sheet music for this available to view anywhere?

Comment: In music theory, the G (major/minor) chord is simply the [mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant) chord of the E major/minor key. The tonal separation of a third is generally considered to be harmonic. There may be something more here, but I can't tell without seeing the sheet music.

Comment: @Noldorin the mediant is diatonic, meaning it would be G# in the key of E major.

Comment: @Noldorin: http://cleantab.com/golden-train-guitar-tab/justin-nozuka/v1

Comment: I was confused at first because the recording is actually in the key of Ab...

Comment: @rshallit Good catch. I have played this song before so I should have remembered o_O. I am guessing the OP is taking the chords from guitar notation that indicates them relative to a 4th fret capo.

Comment: I've edited the question to refer to the chords that sound, since this is a theory question and guitar is not a transposing instrument.

Comment: @NReilingh Luckily, I used roman numeral notation (mostly) so my answer (mostly) stands. Although, technically, since this is a *theory* question, the actual notes aren't that important. ;)

Comment: @Rein True, though OP did provide a YouTube example.

Comment: @NReilingh - my bad, I was thinking about the shape of the chord instead of it's position on the fretboard. Good catch.

Comment: @Rein: Oh yes, so it is. I just mean a "minor third" above I guess!

Comment: @balentaw: Unfortunately, the link to your video went dead.

Comment: Very interesting question! Maybe now when you have some answers you could change the title to something that gives some clues about the question? Have a nice day!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ♭III is a [borrowed chord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrowed_chord) from the parallel minor.

A bit more info: The bIII is commonly followed by the IV, giving it something of a subdominant function relative to the IV. The ii here is acting as a IV (it's the relative minor of IV) in a plagal cadence, so functionally what we have is more similar to I bIII IV, a common rock progression.

Also, the bIII can provide a particularly bluesy sound to an otherwise diatonic progression since it gives a minor pentatonic feel. Eric Clapton was fond of it as well.

Keep in mind that theory is descriptive, rather than prescriptive. Our brains are wired to hear certain sounds as consonant and dissonant, as creating or releasing tension, etc. There's a pretty good chance that Justin picked a bIII because it sounded good or because another song used it, rather than because he wanted to borrow a chord from the parallel minor. Nothing against Justin, he's a great songwriter. This is just how people usually work. However, knowing the theory does help broaden your palette of chord choices.

Comment: Interesting. It could well be this! I did noticed the enharmonicity of the respective major and minor cords, but didn't know this had a technical name.

Comment: The questioner may also just be mistaking the "G chord" for an inversion of the tonic E chord.

Comment: An inversion of the tonic E chord? The tonic E chord is a major chord, which has a G#. The chords in the chorus are E G F#m, or I bIII ii.

Comment: @Noldorin, you could be right. However, I play this on the guitar and the G seems to fit perfectly with what he's playing.

Comment: Added some further info.

Comment: @Noldrin by the way, if this were G# major (a major chord built on the mediant), it would be a [chromatic mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_mediant), which is less common.

Comment: @Rein: Actually *no-one* said it had to major! At least at the time this question was written, it could have been minor, in which case I could have been correct. :-) We must be careful here.

Comment: @balentaw: Yes, I suspected his reply was right anyway. Glad you have an answer at least.

Comment: @Noldorin Well, he said that G is not in the key of E, which is true of E major but not of E minor. If the key had been E minor, my entire analysis would have been wrong as the G major chord is diatonic. Pedantic man, away!

Comment: That's a fair point, I accept it! Did not see his comment saying "not in the key of E".